# (Can I?) How can I access the int value of the next node (tree recursion)

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

So I have a tree defined as follows:

```
data Tree = Node Tree Int Tree | Leaf Int
```

The `Int` for a `Node` in this case is the value at that `Node`. I am trying to check that a tree is balanced, and that the tree is increasing as it's traversed left to right.

To do so I have a recursive function that takes a `(Node left x right)` and checks that the difference in height of `left` and `right` (the nodes below it) is no more than one. I then call balanced again for left and right.

Is it possible to access the `Int` value of `left` and `right`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write a function that returns the integer at the top node:

```
getInt (Node _ i _) = i
getInt (Leaf i) = i
```

E.g.

```
Prelude> getInt $ Leaf 42
42
Prelude> getInt $ Node (Leaf 42) 123 (Leaf 1337)
123
```

Comment: Great! thanks for sharing, I forget the case of leaf, it has also an int, it is a plus one

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, instead of put variables like left and right, use the constructors again:

> Edit, I forget the case of Leaf, it has also an int:

```
data Tree = Node Tree Int Tree | Leaf Int

exampleSumNodes (Node left x right) = (treeToInt left) + x + (treeToInt right)

treeToInt (Node _ n _) = n
treeToInt (Leaf n ) = n
```